# Change the value of the variable used to disbled the button in Angular

Tags: angular

In my project application, there are two buttons named "verify" and "cancel verification". I have used two boolean-type variables to set the disable property when the page loads.

I want to achieve this scenario: when the verify button is clicked it should be immediately disabled and the cancel verification button gets enabled and vice versa.

Here is my code:

**.ts file**

```
     verified: boolean;
     notVerified: boolean;

   ngOnInit() {
      // setting the value from the API call response
      this.verified = // logic
      this.notVerified = // logic
   }

  valiadtionoftherapist(value) {
    if (value === 'true') {
      var data = {
        'verifiedBadge': true,
        '_id': this.id
      };
      document.getElementById('validation').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/verified-copy-3.png');
      this.verified = false;
      this.notVerified = true;
    }
    if (value === 'false') {
      var data = {
        'verifiedBadge': false,
        '_id': this.id
      };
      document.getElementById('validation').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/notverified-copy.png');
      this.notVerified = false;
      this.verified = true;
    }

    // API call

  }
```

**.html file**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn green-button"  (click)="valiadtionoftherapist('true');" [disabled]="verified" translate>
              Verify User
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn red-button"  (click)="valiadtionoftherapist('false');" [disabled]="notVerified" translate>
              Cancel Verfication
            </button>
          </div>
```

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You have your true/false in the if conditions mixed up, you can change it to the following it should work:

```
if (value === 'true') {
      var data = {
        'verifiedBadge': true,
        '_id': this.id
      };
      document.getElementById('validation').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/verified-copy-3.png');
      this.verified = true;
      this.notVerified = false;
    }
    if (value === 'false') {
      var data = {
        'verifiedBadge': false,
        '_id': this.id
      };
      document.getElementById('validation').setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/notverified-copy.png');
      this.notVerified = true;
      this.verified = false;
    }

    // API call
```

Comment: By doing this, I will not achieve what I want!! If verify button is clicked then it should immediate gets disable!! so that the same user cannot be verify multiple times or in other words user should be verified only once not multiple times by clicking on it several times!! Hope you aer getting my point! Thank you

Comment: You can add a third variable like ìnProgress`. Set this to true if you click a button as example

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Apologies I thought it was a bug in the code logic. What Flo suggested above will work. Adding an isLoading or inProgress value and disabling the button immediately (very start of the valiadtionoftherapist function) will disable any additional button clicks. Then just enable it again after the API call has finished.

Comment: By doing this, it is disabling the clickable button but the other button is not getting enabled!

Comment: @JaynaTanawala did you change the true/false values like I showed in the answer? There was an issue with that too when I tested it.

Comment: @DubDJ, yes, I have changed it